# what is the use of 99999999 in dates and END:: in a case statement

Tags: sql, syntax

I'm looking at a query that looks like this

```
CASE
  WHEN empl.hiredate > 0 THEN date(to_char(empl.hiredate, '99999999'::character varying::text))
  ELSE NULL::date
END::timestamp without time zone, i.incidenttimestamp)::double precision / 30::double precision) AS months_of_service_decimal
```

I'm trying to understand what the meaning of 99999999 and what does END:: do

Comment: 1) With `99999999` the author is probably trying to produce a date in the inifinity of the future... the year 9999. 2) With `END::timestamp` the author is casting the resulting value of the whole `CASE` expression into a `timestamp` value.

Comment: @TheImpaler: the `'99999999'` is a format mask for the [`to_char()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: That expression is horrible. Storing DATE values as numbers is a really, really bad choice to begin with. Casting things back and forth without any reason simply shows that whoever wrote that didn't really understand what's going on (and the casting back and forth is a direct result of the bad design decision to store a date as a number value).

Answer (score 4):

`99999999` is the format argument of [`to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).

`end` just closes the `case` expression, which, as a whole, is followed by a cast - `::timestamp`.